# How avoid type repetition for inherited fields in Scala

Tags: java, scala, types

I start slow migration from Java to Scala and facing issues.
One of them is clumsy constructor arguments. 
I know I cannot avoid them, but at least I would like to introduce some sort
of type alias like C++ has typename to be used in subclasses.

```
case class A[E <: Throwable]
(
  mappers: Map[Class[_ :< Throwable], ExceptionMapper[_ <: Throwable]]
) {
}

case class B[CompletionException]
(
  mappers: Map[Class[_ :< Throwable], ExceptionMapper[_ <: Throwable]]
) extends A(mappers) {
}
```

So in sample above mappers field has horrible type and I would like to type it once in base class only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Scala you can introduce type alias

```
type M = Map[Class[_ <: Throwable], ExceptionMapper[_ <: Throwable]]

class A[E <: Throwable]
(
  mappers: M
) {
}

class B[CompletionException]
(
  mappers: M
) extends A(mappers) {
}
```

By the way, **case** classes shouldn't extend each other because of issues with `equals`/`hashCode`.